# In Rust, what is the best way to print something between each value in a container?

Tags: rust

I want to print every item in a vector separated by commas. You could use numeric indexing:

```
for i in 0..vec.len() {
    print!("{}", vec[i]);
    if i < vec.len() - 1 {
        print!(", ");
    }
}
```

But what if you just have an `Iterator`? You either need to treat the first or last value specially, or create a custom iterator, which seems like a lot of work.

Is there a cleaner idiomatic way of expressing this in Rust?

Comment: Bear in mind that anything using `range(0, vec.len())` is probably not the right way of doing it; iteration is the preferred way of doing things, and has the benefit of being more efficient (being able to skip a bounds check).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let first = true;
for item in iterator {
    if !first {
        print(", ");
    }
    print(item);
    first = false;
}
```

Comment: Right, that works. I guess there is no is_first method on iterators? (Oh hey, you're in Melbourne too! What brings you to Rust? :)

Comment: Iterators are very light-weight; there cannot reasonably be a concept of position. One could have a wrapper around an iterator that let encompassed this concept, or if you were working with `iterator.enumerate()`, you could check the first value in the tuple to check if it was 0, but there cannot be a way general to iterators.

Comment: Me? I’m dealing with web things. But this place ain’t designed for such discussions, try irc://irc.mozilla.org/#rust,#rust-offtopic if you like. (I’d rather like to talk—Prince has impressed me for many years, including its coming from Melbourne )

Comment: Hmm, could be worth making a higher-order function if this crops up often enough. It's basically a fold, with the "first" boolean threaded through it. Might be overthinking things though.

Comment: It could certainly be done, but I don’t think the ergonomics are that great. But keeping with external iterators and having something like `.enumerate()` but yielding `(bool, T)` might be nice.

Comment: Why is this answer more "idiomatic" than @shepmaster 's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45134036/1503549)?
(Referring to the Itertools::format answer).
Is it a matter of the years having gone by since 2014?

Comment: @x10an14: for something like this, I *personally* would not be willing to pull in a new dependency for such a small thing. They add up. If I was already using itertools, I’d *consider* using it for this purpose; but my approach or Shepmaster’s unrolled-first-iteration approach will be a tad faster (both to compile and to run) and lighter (itertools’ format uses `Rc` allocation).

Comment: Ahh, okay. I didn't gather that `itertools` was a non-stdlib dependecy. +1!

Answer (score 12):

If you want to avoid using a variable to check if element is first, you can make use of `.take()` and `.skip()` methods of iterators:

```
for e in vec.iter().take(1) {
    print!("{}", e);
}
for e in vec.iter().skip(1) {
    print!(", {}", e);
}
```

or compact all in a fold :

```
vec.iter().fold(true, |first, elem| {
    if !first { print(", "); }
    print(elem);
    false
});
```

Comment: The disadvantage of using something like `fold` is that it snaffles the control flow so that you can’t do things like early break, return, &c. In a simple case like this, that’s fine, of course.

Answer (score 8):

You can do something special for the first element, then treat all subsequent ones the same:

```
let mut iter = vec.iter();
if let Some(item) = iter.next() {
    print!("{}", item);

    for item in iter {
        print!("<separator>{}", item);        
    }
}
```

If you use [`Itertools::format`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.6.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.format), it's even easier:

```
println!("{}", vec.iter().format("<separator>"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Another method:

```
fn main() {
   let a = vec!["May", "June"];
   for (n, s) in a.iter().enumerate() {
      if n > 0 {
         print!(",");
      }
      print!("{}", s);
   }
}
```

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate