# What is the equivalent of the join operator over a vector of Strings?

Tags: string, rust

I wasn't able to find the Rust equivalent for the "join" operator over a vector of `String`s. I have a `Vec<String>` and I'd like to join them as a single `String`:

```
let string_list = vec!["Foo".to_string(),"Bar".to_string()];
let joined = something::join(string_list,"-");
assert_eq!("Foo-Bar", joined);
```

Related:

- [What's an idiomatic way to print an iterator separated by spaces in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941851/whats-an-idiomatic-way-to-print-an-iterator-separated-by-spaces-in-rust)

Answer (score 373, accepted):

In Rust 1.3.0 and later, [`join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.join) is available:

```
fn main() {
    let string_list = vec!["Foo".to_string(),"Bar".to_string()];
    let joined = string_list.join("-");
    assert_eq!("Foo-Bar", joined);
}
```

Before 1.3.0 this method was called [`connect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.connect):

```
let joined = string_list.connect("-");
```

Note that you do not need to import anything since the methods are automatically imported by the [standard library prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/index.html).

`join` copies elements of the vector, it does not move them, thus it preserves the contents of the vector, rather than destroying it.

Comment: Perhaps this has changed, but `SliceConcatExt` is nightly-only.

Comment: @Evert The trait is marked unstable, but its methods are stable so you can use them. You don't need to explicitly `use` the trait because it's in the prelude.

Comment: @shepmaster Is there an iterator equivalent that doesn't require me to collect the vector first?

Comment: @StevePowell [What's an idiomatic way to print an iterator separated by spaces in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36941851/155423).

Comment: @shepmaster If I read your 'reply' correctly, there is a `join` in `itertools`.

Comment: @StevePowell yes. Comments are ephemeral, Q&A are not. Linking to an answer with examples is better for the site and all future visitors instead of putting random answers in a comment that will be deleted. Q&A can be upvoted to let future people know that an answer was useful and encourage more participation in the site..

Comment: Thank you @shepmaster.  Unfortunately, your unadorned reference to another answer was rather cryptic, so it was not at all clear which part of that answer was relevant.  Though your comments, corrections and answers are invariably excellent your style is condescending and off-putting.

Comment: `join` does not work on the empty char literal?

Comment: Does this copy the data from the vector or move it?

Comment: Tried in playground, and apparently the behavior is to copy the elements, not move them.

Answer (score 34):

As mentioned by Wilfred, [`slice::connect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.connect) has been deprecated since version 1.3.0 in favour of [`slice::join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.join):

```
let joined = string_list.join("-");
```

Answer (score 16):

There is a function from the [`itertools`](https://crates.io/crates/itertools/) crate also called [`join`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.7.8/itertools/fn.join.html) which joins an iterator:

```
extern crate itertools; // 0.7.8

use itertools::free::join;
use std::fmt;

pub struct MyScores {
    scores: Vec<i16>,
}

impl fmt::Display for MyScores {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        fmt.write_str("MyScores(")?;
        fmt.write_str(&join(&self.scores[..], &","))?;
        fmt.write_str(")")?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_scores = MyScores {
        scores: vec![12, 23, 34, 45],
    };
    println!("{}", my_scores); // outputs MyScores(12,23,34,45)
}
```

Comment: Users of this code should be aware that it allocates a potentially large string just to throw it away. It is more efficient to write the strings directly to the output. See also [What's an idiomatic way to print an iterator separated by spaces in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36941851/155423), [In Rust, what is the best way to print something between each value in a container?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26644486/155423).

Comment: Understandable, although the question was about the `join`, not the ways how to optimize the formatting algorithm, no?

Comment: `collect` + `join` is faster and adds no dependencies, see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/green-s/fbd0d374b290781ac9b3f8ff03e3245d) for a benchmark

Comment: @murla yeah but it's annoying source code when T implements Display and the separator is a string, but vec.join won't convert them for you. `.iter().map(|x| x.to_string()).collect::<Vec<_>>().join(", ")`