# What's an idiomatic way to print an iterator separated by spaces in Rust?

Tags: rust

I just want a space separated `String` of the argument variables obtained from `std::env::args()`, which I've been creating using the `fold` function like this:

```
std::env::args()
    .fold("".to_string(), |accum, s| accum + &s + " ")
```

However this creates an extra space at the end which is unwanted. I tried using the `truncate` function, but `truncate` doesn't return a `String`, just modifies the existing `String`, and also this would require the creation of an intermediate binding in order to use the `String`'s `len()` call to define how long the truncated `String` should be (which itself would require an intermediate binding due to Rust's current lexical borrowing rules I believe!)

Comment: I believe if you change the lambda expression to `accum + " " + &s`, the trailing space will disappear.

Comment: @Ferruccio This just results in a leading space, I only did it the way around I did because a trailing space is often invisible whereas a leading one can be seen in the formatting. I should have specified leading and trailing spaces are unwanted though.

Comment: There's an [`intersperse`](https://bluss.github.io/rust-itertools/doc/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.intersperse) method in `itertools` if you're willing to add a dependency. I don't think there's a straightforward way to do this with `std`.

Comment: @Dogbert So with `itertools` it looks like you would call `intersperse` on the iterator and then `fold` that iterator into the final `String` by just having `accum + &s` in the fold closure? Seems simple enough, would be nice if something similar to this existed in std though.

Comment: Yes, of course, I should have realized that would happen. I've run into this problem before (using C#). You need to check if `accum` is empty. I'm not sure if this is valid Rust syntax, but I normally do something like: `accum + (if accum == "" {""} else {" "}) + &s`

Comment: @Ferruccio Yes that would work, slightly messier looking closure but nothing too dreadful. Just a note for anyone choosing the `itertools` approach though - there's a `join` function in `itertools` which joins all elements into a single `String` separated by a specified separator.

Comment: @HarveyAdcock you can actually just call `.collect()` on an iterator of `String` and get back a single `String`. But yeah, `join` is even better for you that I completely missed.

Comment: Why all this talk of intersperse in itertools (I see it often)?  Itertools has actual methods for formatting, use [`.join(" ")` or `.format_default(" ")`](http://bluss.github.io/rust-itertools/doc/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.join)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> What's an idiomatic way to **print** all command line arguments in Rust?

```
fn main() {
    let mut args = std::env::args();

    if let Some(arg) = args.next() {
        print!("{}", arg);

        for arg in args {
            print!(" {}", arg);
        }
    }
}
```

Or better with Itertools' [`format`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.format) or [`format_with`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.format_with):

```
use itertools::Itertools; // 0.8.0

fn main() {
    println!("{}", std::env::args().format(" "));
}
```

> I just want a space separated `String`

```
fn args() -> String {
    let mut result = String::new();
    let mut args = std::env::args();

    if let Some(arg) = args.next() {
        result.push_str(&arg);

        for arg in args {
            result.push(' ');
            result.push_str(&arg);
        }
    }

    result
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", args());
}
```

Or

```
fn args() -> String {
    let mut result = std::env::args().fold(String::new(), |s, arg| s + &arg + " ");
    result.pop();
    result
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", args());
}
```

If you use Itertools, you can use the `format` / `format_with` examples above with the [`format!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format.html) macro.

[`join`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.join) is also useful:

```
use itertools::Itertools; // 0.8.0

fn args() -> String {
    std::env::args().join(" ")
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", args());
}
```

In other cases, you may want to use [`intersperse`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.intersperse):

```
use itertools::Itertools; // 0.8.0

fn args() -> String {
    std::env::args().intersperse(" ".to_string()).collect()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", args());
}
```

Note this isn't as efficient as other choices as a `String` is cloned for each iteration.

Comment: If you put the `for` loop inside the `if let`, you do not need to use `fuse`.

Comment: With `itertools`, you can just do `std::env::args().join(" ")` (thanks to OP and @bluss for the tip in the question comments).

Comment: For the `intersperse` example, couldn't you just call `.collect::<String>()` instead of folding?

Comment: @Addison yep! I'm guessing I copy-pasted from the earlier example with `fold` and didn't apply critical thought.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution with iterators, and zero non-stdlib dependencies

(performance wise, this shines in release mode, with optimizations turned on [[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=7f664c15a60b87e0819a6c46529ff00a)])

```rust
use std::iter::once;

fn join_iter<T>(
    mut iter: impl Iterator<Item = T>,
    sep: impl Fn(&T) -> T,
) -> impl Iterator<Item = T> {
    iter.next()
        .into_iter()
        .chain(iter.flat_map(move |s| once(sep(&s)).chain(once(s))))
}

fn examples() {
    let iter = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9].iter().cloned();
    println!("{:?}", join_iter(iter, |v| v - 1).collect::<Vec<_>>());
    // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

    let iter = ["Hello", "World"].iter().cloned();
    let sep = ", ";
    println!("{:?}", join_iter(iter, |_| sep).collect::<String>());
    // "Hello, World"
}

fn args() -> String {
    join_iter(std::env::args(), |_| " ".to_string()).collect()
}

fn main() {
    examples();

    println!("{}", args());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative for

> I just want a space separated `String` of the argument variables obtained from `std::env::args()`

```
fn args_string() -> String {
    let mut out = String::new();
    let mut sep = "";
    for arg in std::env::args() {
        out.push_str(sep);
        out.push_str(&*arg);
        sep = " ";
    }
    out
}

pub fn main() {
    println!("{}", args_string());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version using `fold`

```
fn join<I, T, D>(iter: I, separator: D) -> String
where
    T: Display,
    D: Display,
    I: Iterator<Item = T>,
{
    match iter.fold(None, |a:Option<String>, b| {
        Some(match a {
            None => format!("{}", &b),
            Some(mut a) => {
                write!(a, "{}{}", separator, b).unwrap();
                a
            }
        })
    }) {
        None => String::new(),
        Some(rval) => rval,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", std::env::args().collect::<Vec<_>>().join(" "));
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?