# Concatenate strings with spaces using only conditionals inside of a for-loop body

Tags: string, loops, rust, string-concatenation

I'm doing [Rust Koans](https://github.com/crazymykl/rust-koans) and am stuck on a this question:

```
#[test]
fn for_loops_two() {
    let words: [&'static str; 3] = ["I", "love", "Rust"];
    let space: &str = " ";
    let mut sentence: String = String::new();
    for word in words.iter() {
        // __
    }

    println!("{:?}", sentence);
    assert!(sentence == "I love Rust".to_string());
}
```

I know I need to concatenate the string but this will fail:

```
#[test]
fn for_loops_two() {
    let words: [&'static str; 3] = ["I", "love", "Rust"];
    let mut sentence: String = String::new();
    for word in words.iter() {
        sentence.push_str(word);
    }

    println!("{:?}", sentence); // "ILoveRust"
    assert!(sentence == "I love Rust".to_string());
}
```

I can add a space after each iteration:

```
#[test]
fn for_loops_two() {
    let words: [&'static str; 3] = ["I", "love", "Rust"];
    let space: &str = " ";
    let mut sentence: String = String::new();
    for word in words.iter() {
        sentence.push_str(word);
        sentence.push_str(space);
    }

    println!("{:?}", sentence); // "I Love Rust "
    assert!(sentence == "I love Rust".to_string());
}
```

This will also fail because the final iteration will add a space.

I guess I could write a conditional if we are on the last iteration, but I'm struggling to get the syntax correct.  Moreover, I feel like there is a much better solution for all of this and I just can't figure out syntax.

How can I make the assertion above pass with a conditional in the loop to not add the space on the last iteration?

Comment: There is indeed much more simple: https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=93eeda9e17f3722775ab1a68da8d5058. I let you look at the source of [`join()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.join) that very basic

Comment: That is much better however it asked me do it in inside a for loop join seems to replace that loop which breaks the initial rule set.  Do you see a way to join in the forloop?

Comment: if you can only write in the loop than the only thing I see is to not add the space if your string is empty. But that very ugly. `if sentence.len() != 0 { sentence.push_str(space); } sentence.push_str(word);` And that doesn't produce the desired output if first words are empty.

Comment: See also [the way to answer this without the silly restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36941851/155423).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`slice::join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/slice/trait.SliceConcatExt.html#method.join):

```
#[test]
fn for_loops_two() {
    let words: [&'static str; 3] = ["I", "love", "Rust"];

    let sentence = words.join(" ");

    assert!(sentence == "I love Rust".to_string());
}
```

A note on the linked `SliceConcatExt` trait: it's listed as unstable on the docs, but the *methods* are stable - the above compiles just fine under the current stable edition of Rust.

If you'd rather stick to the constraints of the koan and use a for-loop, you can either use an `if` as you suggest (figuring out whether you're at the end using [`enumerate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate)), or [`pop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.pop) the last space from the end of the string:

```
#[test]
fn for_loops_two_with_len_check() {
    let words: [&'static str; 3] = ["I", "love", "Rust"];
    const SPACE: char = ' ';
    let number_of_words = words.len();
    let mut sentence = String::new();

    for (i, word) in words.iter().enumerate() {
        sentence.push_str(word);
        if i < number_of_words-1 {
            sentence.push(SPACE);
        }
    }

    assert!(sentence == "I love Rust".to_string());
}


#[test]
fn for_loops_two_with_pop() {
    let words: [&'static str; 3] = ["I", "love", "Rust"];
    const SPACE: char = ' ';
    let mut sentence = String::new();

    for word in words.iter() {
        sentence.push_str(word);
        sentence.push(SPACE);
    }
    let _ = sentence.pop();

    assert!(sentence == "I love Rust".to_string());
}
```

Comment: This answer ignores the strict conditions that the OP / koan has placed: you are *only* allowed to edit the code **inside the for loop**. Removing the for loop or adding methods breaks those restrictions. Solutions for the general problem are well-described in [What's an idiomatic way to print an iterator separated by spaces in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36941851/155423)

Comment: @shepmaster thanks for the clear explanation of why you don't feel this answer is correct.

Comment: Ahh the pop at the end is clever! I should have guessed this.

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but here is a solution modifying only the block inside the loop:

```rust
#[test]
fn for_loops_two() {
    let words: [&'static str; 3] = ["I", "love", "Rust"];
    let mut sentence: String = String::new();
    for word in words.iter() {
        if sentence != "".to_string() {
            sentence.push(' ')
        }
        sentence.push_str(word)
    }
    println!("{:?}", sentence);
    assert!(sentence == "I love Rust".to_string());
}
```