# Join iterator of &str

Tags: rust, iterator

How do I convert an [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html)[`<&str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html) to a [`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html), interspersed with a constant string such as `"\n"`?
For instance, given:

```
let xs = vec!["first", "second", "third"];
let it = xs.iter();
```

One may produce a string `s` by [`collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect)ing into a `Vec<&str>` and [`join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.join)ing the result:

```
let s = it
    .map(|&x| x)
    .collect::<Vec<&str>>()
    .join("\n");
```

However, **this unnecessarily allocates memory** for a `Vec<&str>`.

Is there a more direct method?

Comment: Apologies - my original answer removed the iterator but your question is asking how to join an iterator and not allocate the extra vector.

Comment: Looks like the `itertools` crate [doesn't allocate the vector](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e208a26d869de89f6b998e6bcf6b5a77)

Comment: Note that depending on the exact characteristics of your iterator, collecting into a vector of slices and then joining could actually be faster than using Websterix's method or `itertools`, since `SliceConcatExt::join` can calculate the needed size for the full string ahead of time and thus definitely doesn't need to reallocate during accumulation; whereas the other methods may have to reallocate the string. You should definitely benchmark.

Comment: @SebastianRedl But `collect::<Vec<&str>>` would need to reallocate, but it's a lot smaller than the string buffer, so i guess that would be a faster?

Comment: @chpio It has to allocate, but not reallocate if the iterator gives a good size hint.

Comment: [The `once` plus `skip` trick works nicely for this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b5eedf3f4537a263435b35942f7a5334). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66951473/4039050).

Comment: How is this a duplicate?!

Comment: Sorry, but I dont understand the `.map(|&x| x)` part... why is that?

Comment: I also agree with @MattJoiner, this is not a duplicate and there are better answers to this question in 2023. I voted to reopen.

Comment: Question reopened!

Answer (score 33):

You could use the *itertools* crate for that. I use the [*intersperse*](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.intersperse) helper in the example, it is pretty much the *join* equivalent for iterators.

`cloned()` is needed to convert `&&str` items to `&str` items, it is not doing any allocations. It can be eventually replaced by `copied()` when `rust@1.36` gets a stable release.

```rust
use itertools::Itertools; // 0.8.0

fn main() {
    let words = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"];
    let merged: String = words.iter().cloned().intersperse(", ").collect();
    assert_eq!(merged, "alpha, beta, gamma");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=99e553443f1c151e9fa8eb87f2f72063)

Answer (score 22):

You can do it by using [`fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold) function of the iterator easily:

```
let s = it.fold(String::new(), |a, b| a + b + "\n");
```

The Full Code will be like following:

```
fn main() {
    let xs = vec!["first", "second", "third"];
    let it = xs.into_iter();

    // let s = it.collect::<Vec<&str>>().join("\n");

    let s = it.fold(String::new(), |a, b| a + b + "\n");
    let s = s.trim_end();

    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b8669503827b705b0790a3c155209547)

EDIT: After the comment of Sebastian Redl I have checked the performance cost of the fold usage and created a [benchmark test](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0d9e93ec8ddfcbf86f0294c3f011eedf) on playground.

You can see that `fold` usage takes significantly more time for the many iterative approaches.

*Did not check the allocated memory usage though*.

Comment: The reason this is slow is because you're using + to create two new Strings on every iteration. If you use a single string ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f2740a132f69b5d41d14a3472c98674e)) it can work better than collect and join ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=5fa149bbd78707d7ff4e257d38318361)).

Comment: added `black_box` and create the vec for each test individually (because of cache warming) ([playgroud](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=9316d8202ee375f35305c8ec938f5f47)). Playground isn't that good for benchmarking due to massive variance in latency/duration, but the fold variant seems to be slightly slower (over multiple runs).

Comment: [v2](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=6d7a6e7427a715d853ce32440a0ad59e) with `black_box(xs).iter().copied()` takes now twice as long for collect+join over fold (the `black_box(xs)` doesn't matter, `xs` is the same). <3 for microbenchmarking

Comment: I guess they optimize something like `vec!["hey"; 100_000].into_iter().collect<Vec<_>>` to just return the original vec?!

Comment: Yes, [they do](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/alloc/vec/spec_from_iter.rs.html#41)

Comment: @mcdonoughe could this be improved with `String::with_capacity(xs.len())`?

Comment: Another solution is `let mut it = xs.into_iter(); let first = it.next().unwrap_or("").to_owned(); let r = it.fold(first, |a, b| a + "\n" + b);` Then you end up with a `String` instead of `&str`

Comment: @akiner-alkan I've tested today and I see the opposite: fold approach takes 7.405799ms over 10.380536ms in my browser. So I'm still not sure what to use.

Comment: @EirNym you can run the test several times with 'RELEASE' mode instead of 'DEBUG'. On 'DEBUG' mode running benchmark tests can result incorrect than expected since there will be breakpoint pointers and different CPU/memory utilization strategies applied.

Answer (score 9):

With [`itertools`](https://docs.rs/itertools), you have not only [`intersperse()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.intersperse) but also [`join()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.join):

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;

let s = it.join("\n");
```

It is more general than `intersperse()` (it accepts any `Display`-implementing type) but therefore may be slower (I didn't benchmark though).

Answer (score 0):

use [Iterator::reduce](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.reduce).

```rust
fn main() {
    let it = ["1", "2", "3"].into_iter();
    let res = it.map(String::from).reduce(|acc, s| format!("{acc}, {s}")).unwrap_or_default();
    assert_eq!(&res, "1, 2, 3");
}
```

You can use `Cow` to avoid unnecessary allocation.

```rust
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn main() {
    let it = ["1", "2", "3"].into_iter();
    let res = it.map(Cow::from).reduce(|mut acc, s| {
        acc.to_mut().push('\n');
        acc.to_mut().push_str(&s);
        acc
    }).unwrap_or_default();
    assert_eq!(&res, "1\n2\n3");
}
```

Answer (score -4):

there's relevant example in rust documentation: [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map).

```rust
let words = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"];

// chars() returns an iterator
let merged: String = words.iter()
                          .flat_map(|s| s.chars())
                          .collect();
assert_eq!(merged, "alphabetagamma");
```

You can also use `Extend` trait:

```rust
fn f<'a, I: Iterator<Item=&'a str>>(data: I) -> String {
    let mut ret = String::new();
    ret.extend(data);
    ret
}
```

Comment: This answer does not reproducing the OP's needs. OP is asking about interspersed with some constant string (e.g. "\n")?.

Comment: also this should work without `flat_map`, as *String* already implements `Extend<&str>`.