# How do I convert a HashSet of Strings into a Vector?

Tags: vector, rust, hashset, borrowing

I'm trying to convert a `HashSet<String>` into a sorted vector that can then be `join`ed with commas:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let mut hs = HashSet::<String>::new();
    hs.insert(String::from("fee"));
    hs.insert(String::from("fie"));
    hs.insert(String::from("foo"));
    hs.insert(String::from("fum"));

    let mut v: Vec<&String> = hs.iter().collect();
    v.sort();

    println!("{}", v.join(", "));
}
```

This will not compile:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `join` found for struct `std::vec::Vec<&std::string::String>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:13:22
   |
13 |     println!("{}", v.join(", "));
   |                      ^^^^ method not found in `std::vec::Vec<&std::string::String>`
```

I understand why I can't join the `Vec<&String>`, but how can I convert the `HashSet` to a `Vec<String>` instead, so it can be joined?

The examples given in [What's an idiomatic way to print an iterator separated by spaces in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36941851/96233) do not seem to apply because the iterator for `Args` returns `String` values, unlike the iterator for `HashSet` which returns `&String`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's an idiomatic way to print an iterator separated by spaces in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941851/whats-an-idiomatic-way-to-print-an-iterator-separated-by-spaces-in-rust)

Comment: You could call `into_iter` to take ownership of the values.

Comment: *the iterator for `HashSet` which returns `&String`* — one of the many iterators of `HashSet` does that, yes. Others do not. You also can format a `&String` just fine.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I encourage you to re-read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/), specifically [the chapter on iterators](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-02-iterators.html). Next, become familiar with the methods of [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html).

The normal way I'd expect to see this implemented is to convert the `HashSet` to an iterator and then `collect` the iterator to a `Vec`:

```
let mut v: Vec<_> = hs.into_iter().collect();
```

In this case, I'd prefer to use [`FromIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html) directly (the same trait that powers `collect`):

```
let mut v = Vec::from_iter(hs);
```

---

Focusing on your larger problem, use a `BTreeSet` instead, coupled with [What's an idiomatic way to print an iterator separated by spaces in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36941851/155423)

```
use itertools::Itertools; // 0.10.1
use std::collections::BTreeSet;

fn main() {
    // Create the set somehow
    let hs: BTreeSet<_> = ["fee", "fie", "foo", "fum"]
        .into_iter()
        .map(String::from)
        .collect();

    println!("{}", hs.iter().format(", "));
}
```

Comment: I'm part-way through my first reading of _The Rust Programming Language_. I figured out how to make it work by changing to `HashSet<&'static str>`. After that change, the `join` worked. In my case, using `&'static str` is fine since the HashSet contains only string literals.

Comment: How come this `Vec::from_iter(hs)` works, when `hs` is a HashSet (and not an iterator)?

Comment: @MEMark review the definition of `FromItetator` and you’ll see it accepts any value that can be *turned into* an iterator, not that is only already an iterator.

Answer (score 4):

There's a straightforward way to convert a `HashSet` of `String`s into a `Vec` of `String`s using the turbofish (`::<>`):

```
let result_vec = result_set.into_iter().collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Comment: Specifying the type on both the variable _and_ via the turbofish is redundant. Specifying the type inside the collection is also redundant. I'd write it as `let result_vec = result_set.into_iter().collect::<Vec<_>>()`.