# How can I join a Vec<> of i32 numbers into a String?

Tags: rust

I want to join a list of numbers into a String. I have the following code:

```
let ids: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
ids.push(1);
ids.push(2);
ids.push(3);
ids.push(4);
let joined = ids.join(",");
print!("{}", joined);
```

However, I get the following compilation error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `join` found for struct `std::vec::Vec<i32>` in the current scope
  --> src\data\words.rs:95:22
   |
95 |     let joined = ids.join(",");
   |                      ^^^^ method not found in `std::vec::Vec<i32>`
   |
   = note: the method `join` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `<[i32] as std::slice::Join<_>>::Output = _`
```

I'm a bit unclear as to what to do. I understand the implementation of traits, but whatever trait it's expecting, I would expect to be natively implemented for `i32`. I would expect joining integers into a string to be more trivial than this. Should I cast all of them to `String`s first?

**EDIT**: It's not the same as [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941851/whats-an-idiomatic-way-to-print-an-iterator-separated-by-spaces-in-rust), because here I am specifically asking about numbers not being directly "`join`able", and the reason for the trait to not be implemented by the number type. I looked fairly hard for something in this direction and found nothing, which is why I asked this question.

Also, it's more likely that someone will search specifically for a question phrased like this instead of the more general "idiomatic printing of iterator values".

Comment: I also think the linked question is not quite a duplicate. I believe there is a substantial difference between creating a string by joining `Vec<i32>` and *printing* something like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the [`[T]::join()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.join) method requires that `[T]` implements the [`Join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.Join.html) trait. The `Join` trait is only implemented for `[T]` where `T` implements `Borrow<str>` (like `String` or `&str`) or `Borrow<[U]>` (like `&[U]` or `Vec<U>`). In other words, you can only join a vector of strings or a vector of slices/vectors.

In general, Rust requires you to be very explicit about type conversion, so in many cases you shouldn't expect the language to e.g. automatically convert an integer to a string for you.

To solve your problem, you need to explicitly convert your integers into strings before pushing them into your vector:

```rust
let mut ids: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
ids.push(1.to_string());
ids.push(2.to_string());
ids.push(3.to_string());
ids.push(4.to_string());
let joined = ids.join(",");
print!("{}", joined);
```

[Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c77e747ba783656d78fe05580fd5b6a5)

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to explicitly convert into string, then you can use [Itertools::join](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9.0/itertools/fn.join.html) method (this is an external crate though)

[PlayGround](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4237b9fb57d535326a6d4c6f324090e1)

Relevant code:

```
use itertools::Itertools;

let mut ids: Vec<i32> = ...;
let joined = Itertools::join(&mut ids.iter(), ",");
print!("{}", joined);
```

Frxstrem suggestion:

```
let joined = ids.iter().join(".");
```

Comment: Since `Itertools` is a trait, you can also write `ids.iter().join(",")`. Seems a bit cleaner to me. ([Modified playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f5b66c9a3ac4abe7483c2f37d5ad0b57))

Comment: Generally, I prefer the functional style.

Comment: Please don't edit answers to change them. Create your own answer and earn jucy jucy karma! Editing is to remove errors/typos, not for changing answers. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

I would do

```
let ids = vec!(1,2,3,4);
let joined: String = ids.iter().map( |&id| id.to_string() + ",").collect(); 
print!("{}", joined);
```

Generally when you have a collection of one type in Rust, and want to turn it to another type, you call `.iter().map(...)` on it. The advantage of this method is you keep your ids as integers which is nice, have no mutable state, and don't need an extra library. Also if you want a more complex transformation than just a casting, this is a very good method. The disadvantage is you have a trailing comma in `joined`. [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9e277302034ab522622965398d2b36ac)

Comment: I'd probably map a `.to_string()` and then call `.join()`, but thanks for your input!

Comment: You can use `std::write()!` to avoid that temporary heap allocation (id.to_string()). [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b357054d9b340fdb7504e4e5f192be81)

Comment: This won't give you the answer you expect as it will have a trailing separator. e.g. `vec![1, 2, 3, 4]` will become `1,2,3,4,`

Answer (score 1):

If you want a generic solution:

```
fn join<I, T>(it: I, sep: &str) -> String
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = T>,
    T: std::fmt::Display,
{
    use std::fmt::Write;

    let mut it = it.into_iter();
    let first = it.next().map(|f| f.to_string()).unwrap_or_default();

    it.fold(first, |mut acc, s| {
        write!(acc, "{}{}", sep, s).expect("Writing in a String shouldn't fail");
        acc
    })
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(join(Vec::<i32>::new(), ", "), "");
    assert_eq!(join(vec![1], ", "), "1");
    assert_eq!(join(vec![1, 2, 3, 4], ", "), "1, 2, 3, 4");
}
```

Maybe this implement

If you prefer that style, you can use an extension method:

```
trait JoinIterator {
    fn join(self, sep: &str) -> String;
}

impl<I, T> JoinIterator for I
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = T>,
    T: std::fmt::Display,
{
    fn join(self, sep: &str) -> String {
        use std::fmt::Write;

        let mut it = self.into_iter();
        let first = it.next().map(|f| f.to_string()).unwrap_or_default();

        it.fold(first, |mut acc, s| {
            write!(acc, "{}{}", sep, s).expect("Writing in a String shouldn't fail");
            acc
        })

    }
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(Vec::<i32>::new().join(", "), "");
    assert_eq!(vec![1].join(", "), "1");
    assert_eq!(vec![1, 2, 3, 4].join(", "), "1, 2, 3, 4");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea! I think I am not a fan of the repeated string allocations and copying. I would hope that the `String::join` method only does one big allocation, but I haven't checked. In any case, it's good to keep this alternative in mind. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DanielGray You're right, I've updated my code.