# Flatten Iterator of Strings to Vec<char> (or even FromIterator<char>)

Tags: rust

As the title says, I have an `Iterator` of `String`s and would like to produce a `Vec<char>`, just by concatenating all of them (and while considering each `String` as a sequence of Unicode Scalar Values, as `.chars()` does). (I don't need to interleave a string between the `String`s or anything like that, although I understand it wouldn't be much harder with, e.g. `itertools::intersperse`, as covered in [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36946085/3243497).)

```
pub fn flatten_strings(ss: impl Iterator<Item=String>) -> Vec<char> {
    // ???
}
```

(It would be nice, but not particularly necessary, if I could implement the slightly more general type signature:)

```
pub fn flatten_strings<S>(ss: impl Iterator<Item=String>) -> S where S: FromIterator<char> {
    // ???
}
```

Anyway, here's a simple attempt:

```
pub fn flatten_strings(ss: impl Iterator<Item=String>) -> Vec<char> {
    ss.flat_map(|s| s.chars()).collect()
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, because `chars` returns [`Chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html), which contains a reference to the `String` it's based on; but the lambda took ownership of the `String` and will drop it when it returns.

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing function parameter `s`
 --> src/main.rs:2:21
  |
2 |     ss.flat_map(|s| s.chars()).collect()
  |                     -^^^^^^^^
  |                     |
  |                     returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
  |                     `s` is borrowed here
```

I can fix this by just collecting all the `String`s into an intermediate vector, so that I have somebody owning all the `String`s, and am flatmapping an iterator of `&String`s instead of `String`s; but having to allocate that intermediate vector of `String`s seems inefficient and somewhat defeat the point of using Rust's nice iterator abstractions:

```
pub fn flatten_strings(ss: impl Iterator<Item=String>) -> Vec<char> {
    ss.collect::<Vec<String>>().iter().flat_map(|s| s.chars()).collect()
}
```

Similarly, I could handroll a loop, but that also seems ugly. Can I implement this function efficiently without additional allocations, but also without leaving Rust's iterator abstractions?

Comment: Related: [How can I store a Chars iterator in the same struct as the String it is iterating on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43952104/how-can-i-store-a-chars-iterator-in-the-same-struct-as-the-string-it-is-iteratin)

Comment: Another one: [Is there an owned version of String::chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47193584/is-there-an-owned-version-of-stringchars)

Comment: Can't you implement `flatten_strings(ss: impl Iterator<Item = &str>) -> impl Iterator<Item = chars> + '_` instead?

Comment: In my use cases, the `String`s in the input iterator are also intermediate values (for example, produced by `map`ping a different iterator with `format!`); I'm trying not to allocate space to hold all of them at once.

Comment: Do the links above answer your question?

Comment: They do in the sense that I understand how any method of producing an owned version of String::chars would produce a corresponding solution to my problem (and one answer has been posted to that effect), but none of the solutions seem perfect to me (either additional allocations, or a LOT of additional code / an extra dependency). I was sort of hoping that the more specific goal of producing a self-owned Vec<char> might enable some better workarounds for this ownership issue, I guess.

Comment: Instead of creating a `Vec<char>`, you could also simply concatenate all the strings into a single string. This will usually consume a lot less memory; an ASCII character consumes one byte in a UTF-8 string, but four bytes in a `Vec<char>`, and English text consists mostly of ASCII characters. You can then use `concatenated_string.chars()` whenever you need it.

Comment: I know, and that's really easy (`String` implements `FromIterator<String>`), but it happens that I want random access to the `char`s (sort of, it's a bit contrived but it's the reason I'm asking this question).

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is that the `s: String` parameter in the closure is dropped before anyone can use the `Chars` object that depends on it.

Here are two ways to deal with that. The first is more verbose than your code, but uses the same type signature. The second relies on an iterator of `&str` that outlive the function and all its `Chars` objects.

```
pub fn flatten_strings(ss: impl Iterator<Item=String>) -> Vec<char> {
    let mut res = Vec::new();
    for s in ss {
        res.extend(s.chars());
    }
    res
}

pub fn flatten_strings2<'a>(ss: impl Iterator<Item=&'a str>) -> Vec<char> {
    ss.flat_map(|s| s.chars()).collect()
}
```

Comment: Hm, now that you wrote out the hand-written loop, I realized that you can easily generalize it to return `S: Default + Extend<char>`, which is implemented by many of the same things that implement `FromIterator<char>`.

Comment: That's quite reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

If you can live with a temporary allocation, you can convert each string to a `Vec<char>` as you progress through the list and provide that to the flat_map. This will let the more general case work too.
You can go slightly more general (as suggested by [Sven Marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279627/sven-marnach)) and just return an `impl Iterator<Item = char>` without the collect, and allow the caller collect if they want.

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use core::iter::FromIterator;
pub fn flatten_strings(ss: impl Iterator<Item=String>) -> Vec<char> {
    ss.flat_map(|s| s.chars().collect::<Vec<_>>()).collect()
}

pub fn flatten_strings2<S>(ss: impl Iterator<Item=String>)  -> S where S: FromIterator<char>  {
    ss.flat_map(|s| s.chars().collect::<Vec<_>>()).collect()
}

pub fn flatten_strings3(ss: impl Iterator<Item=String>)  -> impl Iterator<Item = char>  {
    ss.flat_map(|s| s.chars().collect::<Vec<_>>())
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec!["A string ".to_string(), "another".to_string() ];
    println!("{:?}",flatten_strings(v.clone().into_iter()));
    let h: HashSet<char> = flatten_strings2(v.clone().into_iter());
    println!("{:?}",h);
    let h: HashSet<char> = flatten_strings3(v.clone().into_iter()).collect();
    println!("{:?}",h);
}
```

Comment: Instead of returning a type `S: FromIterator<char>`, you could also simply return an `impl Iterator<Item = char>` and let the caller use it in whatever way they choose.