# How do I insert values between each element of a list?

Tags: arrays, list, rust

This ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7e172371cae5ed2e0a692aa2a1416b15)):

```rust
let s = "Hello world!";
let splitted_string = s.split_terminator("").skip(1).collect::<Vec<&str>>();
println!("splitted_string: {:?}", splitted_string);
```

results in the following output:

```
splitted_string: ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "w", "o", "r", "l", "d", "!"]
```

How can I insert an `a` between each element and obtain something like this?

```
["H", "a", "e", "a", "l", "a", "l", "a", "o", "a", " ", "a", "w", "a", "o", "a", "r", "a", "l", "a", "d", "a", "!"]
```

Comment: The `itertools` crate [has a function for this](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.intersperse), and there's also [an unstable `Iterator` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.intersperse).

Comment: [What's an idiomatic way to print an iterator separated by spaces in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36941851/155423)

Comment: [Alternative](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2e8f79de2c6fc2499d41c5315ef3f2aa)

Comment: Same with my previous alternative but with new features: [Alternative](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f9ae2b2422223fb6178ec1dbadacdcb8)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's already a good `.flat_map()` answer, but to give a slightly different approach for the sake of variety, we can shave that extra 'a' off the end by using `.take()`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let s = "Hello world!";
    
    let interspersed = s.chars()
                        .flat_map(|c| [c, 'a'])
                        .take(s.chars().count() * 2 - 1)
                        .collect::<String>();
                        
    println!("interspersed: {:?}", interspersed);
}
```

output:

```
interspersed: "Haealalaoa awaoaralada!"
```

I've updated the answer to account for the case where the number of bytes in a string doesn't match the number of bytes by applying `s.chars().count()` instead of `s.len()`. Note that `s.chars().count()` is an `O(n)` operation.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work properly if the string has non-ascii characters, since `s.len()` is the length in bytes, while `s.chars()` has fewer characters. This means you end up with a `a` at the end. For e.g., "abç" -> "aabaça"

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues Thank you for pointing that out. I've updated the answer to use `s.chars().count()` instead.

Answer (score 5):

It is still experimental, but [`iter::intersperse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.intersperse) does exactly that.

From the doc [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=37e7c2ebfac1c284f0c196cca46328f7):

```rust
#![feature(iter_intersperse)]

let mut a = [0, 1, 2].iter().intersperse(&100);
assert_eq!(a.next(), Some(&0));   // The first element from `a`.
assert_eq!(a.next(), Some(&100)); // The separator.
assert_eq!(a.next(), Some(&1));   // The next element from `a`.
assert_eq!(a.next(), Some(&100)); // The separator.
assert_eq!(a.next(), Some(&2));   // The last element from `a`.
assert_eq!(a.next(), None);
```

In the meanwhile, the [`itertools::intersperse`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.1/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.intersperse) crate has the same functionality.

A solution that only uses the current stable standard library:

```rust
use std::iter;
fn main() {
    let s = "Hello world!";
    let result: Vec<char> = s
        .chars()
        .zip(iter::repeat('a'))
        .flat_map(|(a, sep)| vec![sep, a])
        .skip(1)
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

Results:

```
['H', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'l', 'a', 'l', 'a', 'o', 'a', ' ', 'a', 'w', 'a', 'o', 'a', 'r', 'a', 'l', 'a', 'd', 'a', '!']
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5f3fd8e55d150c3fb5e2506e17deceb4)

Comment: The currently proposed standard library solution suffers from the fence post problem adding an extra `'a'` at the end. You could solve this by essentially doing [what itertools does](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.1/src/itertools/intersperse.rs.html#75-87).

Comment: @FynnBecker, indeed. He changed it, fixed now. thanks for the heads up!