# Must one collect to a vector to join?

Tags: rust

My following Rust code

```
println!(
    "{}\n",
    cavern
        .iter()
        .map(|row| row
            .iter()
            .map(|x| x.to_string())
            .collect::<Vec<_>>()
            .join(""))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        .join("\n")
);
```

Is much shorter in Python:

```
print("\n".join("".join(map(str, row)) for row in cavern))
```

or in Haskell:

```
putStrLn (unlines (map (>>= show) cavern))
```

One of the main reasons is there's no need to collect the iterators before joining. Is there a way to skip this step in Rust too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the identically-named [`join`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.3/itertools/fn.join.html) function from the `itertools` crate. But using `collect` and `join` is apparently [faster](https://gist.github.com/green-s/fbd0d374b290781ac9b3f8ff03e3245d). Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66951473/4317297) answer.